# Post data as a multi-dimensional array and assign values to typed object

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, multidimensional-array, http-post

I need to take :

```
<input type="text" name="option[0]['value']" value="test@email.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="option[0]['option_key']" value="email_from" />

<input type="checkbox" name="option[1]['value']" value="1" checked="checked"/>
<input type="hidden" name="option[1]['option_key']" value="email_asHtml" />
```

from a form and be able to access the values to asing it to a typed object.  I have been trying to get this to run.  What i have done is loaded, [FastMember](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) to help get the job done, but I can even get passed the error throwen of

> Exception converting param 'option' to System.Collections.Object[].
>   Check inner exception for details

From

```
public void save_config(dynamic[,] option)
{
    site.options.Clear();
    foreach (Hashtable item in option)
    {
        options tmp = new options();
        var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(tmp.GetType());
        foreach (string key in item.Keys)
        {
            accessor[tmp, key] = item[key];
        }
        site.options.Add(tmp);
    }

    ActiveRecordMediator<site>.Save(site);
    RedirectToAction("configuration");
}
```

One thought I had was that I could skip the argument so i don't get the binding error and call the param by using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["option"];
```

But then how to break that down is unknown.

**The question here is how to use a Multidimensional Array post data value like you can in php.**

---UPDATE---
So explaining why in the comments that this is not to be just written off as, "you don't know what your doing" style of comments *(not meaning it in a bad why, just the way i took it)*, I did think of an new rount that may work better. *(see they were oddly helpful :D)*

So in stead of sending the post data as i was, I'll remove the muiltde and go for a little simplar array set up so i can use the same trick i listed in the comment.  Before I was trying to send the data like this.

```
option[0]['value'] = usedev
option[0]['option_key'] = email_from
option[1]['value'] = 1
option[1]['option_key'] = asfasf
```

If I just use the key to join the two values I need I can then get the length of "value" then loop over it with an var i++ and get the values i needed.  Simple you just need to move the data to this pattern:

```
option_key[0]   usedev
option_key[1]   email_from
value[0]    1
value[1]    asfasf
```

and it would work fine to then call it in a loop as

```
string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["value[" + i+ "]"];
string option_key= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["option_key[" + i+ "]"];
i++;
```

Then all will be good.  I'll post the final solution when I'm done.

--Secound Update--

So flatting to out of the multi-dimensional array and using the array keys as the tie as if it was a multi-dimensional array lets you get the values.  The deal is that it'd be better if the i was not an iterated value.  This is what I have.  I beleive the

```
    public void save_config(
            [ARDataBind("site", Validate = true, AutoLoad = AutoLoadBehavior.NewRootInstanceIfInvalidKey)] site site,
        String[] value,
        String[] option_key
        ) {
        site.options.Clear();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (String item in value) {

            options tmp = new options(){
                value = item,
                option_key = option_key[i]
            };
            i++;
            site.options.Add(tmp);
        }
        ActiveRecordMediator<site>.Save(site);
        RedirectToAction("configuration");
    }
```

---

I believe the anwser is that C# is not able to handle multi-dimensional mixed type arrays

Comment: Usually you don't do such horrible things in solid platforms like .NET. You need to re-think your approach. Adapt or die! :)

Comment: That is not helpful and or even needed.  I'm aware of what I'm asking for and know there is a solution that can be had.

Comment: Sorry, but IMHO, you need to re-think your solution. I would start studying the platform. Don't try to use PHP approaches in other environments and languages. Be agree or not, but it's a good suggestion!

Comment: Agree or not, IMHO it's not good to suggest that trying to fix a missing post procedure that you can do in php with no sweat that is grounds to rethink when you have no idea of the scoop of the total project.  Think of it as the challenge of “are you good enough to know how”, not why you believe it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm trying to give you a hint: probably you're using a bad approach to solve the problem and if you do it well using PHP it's not a good reason to think that you can use the same approach in other environments. Anyway, it's not about saying "I'm good enough to know how" but "I know you're in the wrong way and you're overcomplicating things just because you want to mimic PHP"!

Comment: :D sorry again, not helping awser the question.  I've done something close to this.  If you have ever done mass file uploads that are ajaxed with file poperties like a name, captions etc, then you'll now the hell it can be in C# to get an asscatate object together with out hardcoding.  When I did that, I used the uploaded file name as the key and then used foreach(String key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys) to access them like HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["caption[" + Fname + "]"].  There are ways.  Telling me I am overcomplicating is not helpful to me, i know the complications

Comment: Start by explaining your **actual** requirements in your question and someone will tell how to solve your problem in a better way than your current approach. And since I don't know your requirements, I didn't answer your question. That's why I'm using comments, sir!

Comment: I need to get `  options tmp = new options(){value="",option_key=""};   site.options.Add(tmp); `  looped to pick up all values and then add them to the site typed object.

Comment: Usually you answer your question with an answer. This is possible in SO.

Comment: are you using web forms or MVC?  Also are you using either server side controls (web forms) or model binding (MVC)?

Comment: @ken it's castle mvc but I can't use the ARDataBind on the site type since the the HasMany relation of the site type to the optioon types needs Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer "SO"?

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC SO = StackOverflow

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC, I assume you mean MonoRail?  I'm not familiar with but my understanding is that your controller should be binding the posted data to models.  Are you using the same patterns described here: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Controllers-Data-Binding&NS=MonoRail&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Array_Support_6

Comment: @KenHenderson correct. MonoRail ARDataBind is leveraged in the model defined as type `site`.  This type has a HasMany relationship with the type `option` with a property of `Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan` which will upon deletion of the type `site` any and all `option` entries will be removed as well.  The app follows what you see in the doc but this AllDeleteOrphan causes an issue in the model relation where you can't do an input name of "site.option[0].value". Normally it works, so I was bypassing the issue by skipping the ARDataBind and clearing the `option`s on `site`

Comment: I am trying to do a post requestion from C# to a CakePHP appliation which needs an array formatted as `[_method=.x, data=>[]]` so I understand your problem. I think I'm doing something wrong so that is why I was Googeling this, but one thing you might want to know of is [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which allows you to convert a json string to c# objects. Maybe that way you can figure something out (like: converting your array to a json string to know the structure, convert it to c# and go from there). Don't know if it helps, but I think it's worth sharing.